On the blow-up of a cone at the origin
I'm trying to solve an excercise on the blow-up of the affine cone $\mathcal{Z}(xy-z^2)\subset \mathbb{A}^3$ at the origin.
Let $\sigma:X'\rightarrow \mathbb{A^3}$ be the blow-up of the affine space at the point $O=(0,0,0)$. My goal is to show that the variety $V'=\overline{\sigma^{-1}(V\setminus\{0\})}$ is smooth.
By setting coordinates $(x,y,z),[u:v:w]$ on $\mathbb{A}^3\times\mathbb{P}^2$, I computed the equations of $V'$, obtaining:
\begin{array}{rl}
xv-yu=0\\
yw-zv=0\\
xw-zu=0\\
xy-z^2=0.\end{array}
Then, I proceeded locally, by checking smoothness on the affine chart $\{u\neq0\}$. Hence, setting for instance $u=1$, I found the following equations:
\begin{array}{rl}
xv-y=0\\
xw-z=0\\
x^2(v-w^2)=0.\end{array}
However, it appears to me that the points corresponding to $x=0$ are singular, contraddicting the request. What am I missing?

These equations describe the full transform in $X$. To get the strict transform you should divide the last equation by $x^2$ (note that $x = 0$ is the equation of the exceptional divisor of $X$). Then the last equation is $v = w^2$, and it follows that $x$ and $w$ are local coordinates.

Thank you. I don't quite get when you say "it follows that $x$ and $w$ are local coordinates"... what about $y,z,v$? How can I visualize what is happening?

Your equations imply $v = w^2$, $y = xw^2$, and $z = xw$.
